# Creating 3D Models for Game similar to Tron in Blender

Tags: models, blender

How can I create 3D Model of objects with glowing edges (just like in Tron) using Blender ?

Note : I am a beginner in Blender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a video tutorial of someone doing tron-textures in Blender.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssMQCdjHWNI&feature=relmfu

The first 3 parts of the tutorial are the relevant parts (unwrapping a model and painting a texture on it), Part 4 starts going into Blender's node system, which you won't be using if you're using a different game engine.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.blenderguru.com/create-a-glowing-neon-sign) is a good tutorial by Andrew Price to get you started.

Comment: It's not tron related. But it's a neon sign tutorial